# for OpenCV build Error C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, android-ndk

I am new in OpenCV ,now I working on OpenCV Project. I have download the OpenCV sdk and ndk also.
I have change the  **gradle.properties** as per tutorials instruction

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I have also include the ndk directories in **local.properties**

 When I compile the project on Android Studio I found build error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

  > Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
  >   Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
  >   https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
  >   Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
  >   https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html
  >
  > - Try:
  >     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with - -info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  > - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Are you using that old approach of using *Android.mk* file for use of **NDK**?

Comment: Check it out from here : https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/#native-project

Comment: yes I am using old approach .

Comment: You need to remove line `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`, and create new **cmake** file to integrate **NDK** in your project, let me know if you need help.

Comment: As I am totally new to ndk I don't know how to create Cmake file .. :(

Comment: Okay, just follow that above link and let me know if you've stuck at anything.

Comment: yeah, it is different from Android Studio's usage, maybe you could try this one: https://gist.github.com/tzutalin/f07f5633fd599001101006561689062b.  Android Studio's CMake support is also from take-no-me's cmake port, should not be difficult to make it to work with android studio. will let you know

Comment: You don't need to use CMake. ndk-build is also supported. If the project is already written for ndk-build then use that.